# Ошибка в кодировке python

Tags: python

Помогите как решить проблему ? это мой первый код на python...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os


URL = 'https://auto.ria.com/newauto/marka-jeep/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0', 'accept': '*/*'}
HOST = 'https://auto.ria.com'
FILE = 'cars.csv'


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('a', class_='na-card-item')

    cars = []
    for item in items:
        cars.append({
            'title': item.find('div', class_='na-card-name').get_text(strip=True),
            'link': HOST + item.find('span', class_='link').get('href'),
            'usd_price': item.find('strong', class_='green').get_text(),
            'city': item.find('svg', class_='svg_i16_pin').find_next('span').get_text(),
        })
    return cars


def save_file(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['name'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['title']])


def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        cars = get_content(html.text)
        save_file(cars, FILE)
    else:
        print('Error')


parse()
```

ошибка выползает

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 51, in <module>
    parse()
  File "parser.py", line 46, in parse
    save_file(cars, FILE)
  File "parser.py", line 39, in save_file
    writer.writerow([item['title']])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 26-27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Попробуйте указать кодировку `open(path, 'w', encoding='cp1251')` или `open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-8')` в `save_file`

Comment: Не помогло with open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Значит у вас python2, а это нужно указывать когда пишете вопрос.

Comment: точно... Python 2.7.12
как решить в таком случае проблему ?

Comment: Переходить на python3) Серьезно, официальная поддержка python2 заканчивается в этом году, лучше сразу начинать изучать python с python3. По вашему вопросу: можно попробовать использовать io.open вместо open, как советуют в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10975371/4752653).

Comment: Спасибо, перешел на python 3 и все заработало